# How to set onTouchEvent on Bitmap image using canvas.

Tags: android

i'm new in android development. I wanted to set onTouchEvent particularly for an image. so that i can do some work ,like increase score etc....

Here is the sample code i tried..

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
          canvas.drawBitmap(image1, random.nextInt(455), random.nextInt(270), paint);
          canvas.drawText("SCORE = "+score, 10, 20, paint);
    }

     @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(toggelFlag)
    {
        score = score+10;

    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);

}
```

Actually i wanted to increase the score once i touch the image only. But here if i touch anywhere in the screen its increase the score. I want it for image only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Region object with the image bounds like this:

```
Region region = new Region(left, top, right, bottom);
```

left, top, right and bottom define the image bounds.

Then, when you handle a touch event check if region contains the event position. Would be:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    if(region.contains((int)x, (int)y))
    {
        // touch in image
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If I have been helpful, you should mark my response as valid ;)

Comment: thank you very much.its working..but i'm not getting how to give the value for left, top, right and bottom define the image bounds..properly

Comment: i used    x = random.nextInt(455);
          y = random.nextInt(270);
   r = random.nextInt(455);
          b = random.nextInt(270);

Comment: In the rectangle defined by the image position, the values are: left(value x of top-left point), top(value Y of top-left point), right(value X of bottom-right point) and bottom(value Y of bottom-right point)

Comment: I tried like that..sometimes its working properly but sometimes not..actually  i want the event once i touch the image..@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {_X = (int) event.getX(); _Y = (int) event.getY();
r = random.nextInt(455);b=random.nextInt(270);l=random.nextInt(455);
t = random.nextInt(270);*/
setFocusable(true);
  region = new Region(x, y, r, b);
    //region = new Region(getWindowVisibility(), getWindowAttachCount(), getWindowVisibility(), getWindowVisibility());
  
  if(region.contains(_X, _Y))
  {score = score + 20;
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...
Set onTouch listener to imageview...

1.Take on Linearlayout and add child like this

```
linear.addView(new CustomImage(this)); 
        linear.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return true;
            }
        });
```

2.CustomImage extens view ,Your onDraw method is in this class should be like this.

```
    private CustomImage  extends View
    {
       @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
   {
          canvas.drawBitmap(image1, random.nextInt(455), random.nextInt(270), paint);
          canvas.drawText("SCORE = "+score, 10, 20, paint);
    }
```